# How to instantiate a navigation controller from another view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

My goal is whenever i click a button on a first view controller, then it will navigate to another controller which is a navigation controller.

firstViewController and secondViewController has no connection or anything.

Picture

[image]

I used this code

```
 @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

     let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondViewCtrl") as! SecondViewController
     self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

 }
```

The reason why i instatiate so that I could pass data like

```
vc.name = "Myname"
```

The problem with this code is that it doesn't present navigation bar and as well as the tab bar. What should I do to show both?

**Updated question**

```
 @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    guard let tabBarController = tabBarController else { return }
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1


            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("trackYourGenie") as! TrackYourGenieViewController
            let navController = tabBarController.viewControllers![1]
            let secondViewController = navController.topViewController
            vc.name = "Myname"


 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A safe approach:

```
guard let tabBarController = tabBarController else { return }
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
```

---

If you need to access to your tabBarController to pass datas you can do simply:

```
let navController = tabBarController.viewControllers[1]! as! UINavigationController
let secondViewController = navController.topViewController
```

---

Your method could be:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    guard let tabBarController = tabBarController else { return }
    let navController = tabBarController.viewControllers[1]! as! UINavigationController
    let secondViewController = navController.topViewController as! SecondViewController
    secondViewController.name = "my name"
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

Comment: where do i put this? in view did load?

Comment: @airsoftFreak you could put it in your buttonTapped

Comment: Im generally new in this, could you please show it in full code. Thanks

Comment: the reason why instatiate so that I could pass the data to another view. see my updated question.

Comment: @airsoftFreak: look my update:  you have just all you needed, you dont need to re-instantiate tabBarControllers, simply use it.

Comment: I updated the question, but Im still super confused.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but I received this error where it says 'UiView controller has no member of topViewController' it happened on this line `let secondViewController = navController.topViewController as! SecondViewController`

Comment: The "topViewController" come from UINavigationController types, so simply force as! UINavigationController your navController and check it now..

Comment: Pay attention: this answer and other answers count the firstController as "the index 0" and the navigationController connected to SecondViewController as "the index 1" in tabBarController.viewControllers list's. If you want to know the order simply add print(tabBarController.viewControllers) or make "po self.tabBarController.viewControllers" in your console debug

Comment: Thank you alessandro, you really helped me. I have accepted your answer and now i have a new problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997546/how-to-instantiate-a-navigation-and-tab-controller-from-another-view-controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115436/discussion-between-alessandro-ornano-and-airsoftfreak).

Answer (score 4):

You are instantiating the view controller hence you wouldn't get the navigation bar. To get the navigation bar please instantiate navigation controller and since the second view is only child you would get the second view by default.

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Navigation Controller Id") as! UINavigationController
 self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

The above code should give you the navigation bar.

Comment: It's a mistake, you dont need to re-instantiate a just present navigationController, it's a waste of memory..

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the following code should be sufficient :

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
```

As `UITabBarController` is your `rootViewController`, you can access it with `self.tabBarController`. You don't have to instantiate `UINavigationController` as it is in the storyboard.

Comment: When i do this on viewDidLoad i get nil on tabBarController

Answer (score 1):

I can see from your StoryBoard that you have a TabBarController. If your configuration is that and FirstViewController is on first tab and SecondViewController on second tab, you can just change TabBarController selectedIndex property:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

     tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

If you want to pass data to SecondViewController you can try one of these solutions:

1. `let controller = tabBarController.viewControllers[1] as SecondViewController!
   controller.data = "some data"`
   This soultion could not work since SecondViewController is not ready yet.
2. Create a singleton class where to save data, then retrieve data in SecondViewController viewDidLoad method
3. Save data in UserDefaults, then retrieve data in SecondViewController viewDidLoad method (bad solution if information doesn't have to be persistent)
4. Extend UITabBarController and use it, create a custom var in tabBarController, put data in that variable and then retrieve data in SecondViewController viewDidLoad method

Then clear data if needed.

Comment: Where do i put this? in viewdidload?

Comment: In your buttonTapped IBAction method, look updated answer

Comment: Let say if I want to pass data to other viewController, how would i do that? i updated my question.

Comment: if data has to be persistence should i use core data?

Comment: Data are persistent when you want to maintain them also if app is closed/killed and then re-opened. In that case you should use UserDefaults or SQLite DB or another persistent storage

Answer (score 0):

Navigation will not work from firstViewController as to navigate something we need UINavigationController.

Try Like This

[image]